# ClickListener for Recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What is the current preffered approach for setting up clicklistener for recyclerview items?

Comment: This question has been asked many times here, so how are you doing it and what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView does not have special method attaching click handlers to items unlike ListView. To achieve a similar effect manually, we can attach click listener within the ViewHolder inside our adapter:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView tvName;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        this.tvName.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I'm already using this pattern. What do I need to do if I need click listener for just one item (like a textview?) instead of the whole row?

Comment: I've update the answer for your case

Answer (score 0):

Better to handle onClick() method in viewHolder constructor

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.foo).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try those links, this might help You:

http://www.codexpedia.com/android/defining-item-click-listener-for-recyclerview-in-android/
http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

Comment: I'm using that exact pattern as codexpedia and it works. When I click a row , my code executes. But I would like different action for different item clicks. Like clicking on the image in a row sends you to activity A , clicking on rest of the row sends you to activity B. Could you modify that code for this purpose?

Comment: I would suggest reacting to click event based on clicked position. The `ItemClickListener` in the first approach passes position as the second parameter of it's method `onClick`.